# Python: generate a list containing lists from several lists

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
[1,2,3]
[1]
[1,2,3,4]
```

From the above, I would like to generate a list containing:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,1,4],
[2,1,1], [2,1,2], [2,1,3], [2,1,4],
[3,1,2], [3,1,3],[3,1,4]]
```

What is this process called?

Generate a factorial of python lists?

Is there a built-in library that does this?

Comment: so that's what its called cartesian product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(xs) for xs in itertools.product([1,2,3], [1], [1,2,3,4])]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> lists = [[1,2,3], [1], [1,2,3,4]]  
>>> from itertools import product
>>> map(list, product(*lists))
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4]]
```

Note: the usage of `map` allows me to convert the otherwise tuple results of `product`'s iteration into lists easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
inputList = [[1,2,3], [1], [1,2,3,4]]

import itertools
print [list(item) for item in itertools.product(*inputList)]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 3],
[1, 1, 4],
[2, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 2],
[2, 1, 3],
[2, 1, 4],
[3, 1, 1],
[3, 1, 2],
[3, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answers `itertools.product` is the way to go here, but for completeness and as an illustration of what `itertools.product` does here is a solution using a list comprehension:

```
result = [[x,y,z] for x in [1,2,3] for y in [1] for z in [1,2,3,4]]
```

Here is the same thing using normal for loops which may make it a bit more readable:

```
result = []
for x in [1,2,3]:
    for y in [1]:
        for z in [1,2,3,4]:
            result.append([x, y, z])
```